# Scala init two object from one Trait?

Tags: scala

How can i init two object that extend from the same Trait which the result of

```
trait Test {
    val t= new Website(1)
}
object Test1 extends Test
object Test2 extends Test
```

`Test1.t` and `Test2.t` is the same object. Is it posible in scala ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object SingletonWebsite extends Website(1)

trait Test {
  val t = SingletonWebsite
}
```